# How to iterate on Address Array Object and Set Status of Address Object as True or Flase

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a mat card which displays list of Addresses after grouping them based on Address Type.
HTML Code:

```
 <mat-tab-group>
                      <mat-tab *ngFor="let address of distinctAdressType" label="{{ address }}">
                        <div *ngFor="let element of sampleData.address">
                          <div *ngIf="address.toString() === element.addressType">
                            <br />

                            <mat-label>
                              <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                  Address: {{ element.addressLine1 + ' ' + element.addressLine2 + ' ' + element.addressLine3 }}
                                </div>

                                <div *ngIf="element.addressStatus" >
                                  <i class="fa fa-check" style="font-size:15px;color:green"></i>
                                </div>
                                <ng-template #inActive>
                                  <!-- <i class="fa fa-close" style="font-size:15px;color:red"></i> -->
                                </ng-template>
                              </div>
                            </mat-label>

                            <br />
                            <mat-label> City: {{ element.city }}</mat-label> <br />

                            <br />
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </mat-tab>
                    </mat-tab-group>
```

I want to show a green tick using fa-fa icon if Adress End Date is greater than today's date.
Address Model:

```
class Address {
addressId?: number;
addressType?: string;
city?: string;
country?: string;
endDate?: string;
startDate?: string;
lastUpdatedDate?: string;
lastUpdatedUser?: string;
}
```

Logic to iterate over Array of Address and compare Address date and decide whether to show green tick or no.

```
this.sampleData.address.forEach(address => {
    this.addressType.push(address.addressType);
  });
  this.distinctAdressType = this.addressType.filter(this.onlyUnique);

  // Fetch Address status
  let index = 0;
  this.sampleData.address.forEach(address =>  {

    let addressEndDateObj = new Date(address.endDate);
    console.log('End Date: ', addressEndDateObj);
    //let addressStatus=false;
     if (addressEndDateObj.getTime() >= this.currentDate.getTime())
     {
      this.sampleData.address[index].addressStatus = true;

     } else {

       this.sampleData.address[index].addressStatus = false;
     }
```

I want to check if end Date is less than current date then i want to show a cross fa fa icon and if it's greater than today than green fa fa icon.

Comment: So what is the specific problem and question relating to the code shown?

Answer (score 0):

As you have already written the logic of end date of address is greater or less than the current date and you can simply use that in HTML file for showing green checkmark/red cross mark like this:

```
<div *ngIf="element.addressStatus" >
   <i class="fa fa-check" style="font-size:15px;color:green"></i>
</div>
<ng-template *ngIf="!element.addressStatus">
  <i class="fa fa-close" style="font-size:15px;color:red"></i> 
</ng-template>
```